# SQL SELECT CASE to test and concatenate multiple strings

Tags: sql-server, case

Can this be done?  Trying to concatenate (||) possible multiple results in a SQL CASE statement.

Example: l.Reason could be: 'R01|R04' then Reason should be: "Result1 Result4"

```
SELECT case 
    when CHARINDEX('R01',l.Reason) > 0 then 'Result1'
    when CHARINDEX('R02',l.Reason) > 0 then || ' Result2'
    when CHARINDEX('R03',l.Reason) > 0 then || ' Result3'
    when CHARINDEX('R04',l.Reason) > 0 then || ' Result4'
    end Reason
FROM totals y
```

(SSMS says Incorrect syntax on ||)

Comment: SQL Server uses `CONCAT` and `+` to concatenate strings, not `||`.

Comment: use + for concatenation not ||, but what are you trying to concat?

Comment: do you need to add results in case there is R0x?

Comment: `CASE` is not like an `IF` statement. It is an **expression**. This means you need a **value**, not an operation, as the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LTRIM(
    case when CHARINDEX('R01',t.Reason) > 0 then 'Result1' else '' end
    + case when CHARINDEX('R02',t.Reason) > 0 then ' Result2' else '' end
    + case when CHARINDEX('R03',t.Reason) > 0 then ' Result3' else '' end
    + case when CHARINDEX('R04',t.Reason) > 0 then ' Result4' else '' end
    ) Reason
FROM totals t
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that you look for this solution:

This will create a new text by replacing R01 with 'Result1', R02 with ' Result02? and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE totals (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Reason VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO totals (id, Reason)
VALUES (1, 'R01|R04'),
       (2, 'R01|R03|R05'),
       (3, 'R02|R03'),
       (4, 'R01|R02|R03|R04|R05'),
       (5, 'R01|R05');

SELECT l.reason 'Old Reason',
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(l.Reason, 'R01', 'Result1'),
                    'R02', 'Result2'),
                'R03', 'Result3'),
            'R04', 'Result4'),
        'R05', 'Result5'),
    '|', ' ') AS Reason
FROM totals l --not sure who you use y as an alias
```

| Old Reason | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| R01|R04 | Result1 Result4 |
| R01|R03|R05 | Result1 Result3 Result5 |
| R02|R03 | Result2 Result3 |
| R01|R02|R03|R04|R05 | Result1 Result2 Result3 Result4 Result5 |
| R01|R05 | Result1 Result5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_pq1XOe)